# SQLAlchemy: Using sessionmaker as contextmanger forces to expunge manually

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, contextmanager

I'm using SQLAlchemy and trying to use the sessionmaker as a context manager for my transaction (following the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker.begin)):

```
Session = sessionmaker(some_engine)
with Session.begin() as session:
    query = session.query(SomeTable)
    an_entry = query.one()
    # session.expunge_all()  # Fixes the exception
an_entry.attribute
```

Which raises an `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Instance <AnEntry at 0x7f0a9d1c2560> is not bound to a Session` exception. This can be solved by expunging inside the contextmanager (see the line commented out above).

I'm surprised by this behavior, as the [SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.close) and code indicate that closing a session should automatically expunges all ORM objects. And indeed, the following equivalent of the above works, without me having to manually expunge:

```
Session = sessionmaker(some_engine)
session = Session()
with session.begin():
    query = session.query(SomeTable)
    an_entry = query.one()
an_entry.attribute
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second, "working" example, the context manager is the `SessionTransaction` object returned by `session.begin`, not the session itself.  The session is not closed before accessing the attribute and therefore there is no `DetachedInstanceError`: the instance is never expunged.

A better comparison might be why this code does not raise an error:

```py
with Session() as s:
    an_entry = s.query(SomeTable).one()
an_entry.attribute
```

The reason is that it does not *commit*.  By default, ORM objects are expired when a commit occurs, so a subsequent attribute access requires a query to get the value.  In the case of `with Session.begin() as session:`, the session is committed on leaving the with block, so accessing the attribute requires a query, which requires that the object be attached to a session.

`Session` and `sessionmaker` both accept an `expire_on_commit` boolean keyword argument to control this behaviour.